# iOS: Best approach to parsing HTML and create attributed string and links from this?

Tags: html, ios, regex, nsattributedstring

I am looking for some advice on how to approach this problem.

I am getting a string from an API, which may contain HTML tags, such as italic text, bold text, links, images, paragraphs, etc.

I am probably going to go with [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) which I generally have a lot of love for.

During parsing, I create a string from the original string which strips out all HTML tags. I am using [NSString+HTML](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+HTML.h) from a project for that and that seems to work great.

Now what I want to do is prepare an `NSAttributedString` that `TTTAttributedLabel` can use to display the text with the right formatting.

I also want to prepare links at the same time in a separate array.

I am wondering if Regex is the appropriate way to go, and how exactly I am going to achieve it.

With Regex, I could look for any HTML tags with `<[^>]*>`, however, I would like to know the text in between the tags.

Take the following string as an example:

`The <b>quick</b> brown fox <i>jumps</i> over the <a href="http://dog.com">lazy dog</a>.`

Which should display as:

The **quick** brown fox *jumps* over the [lazy dog](http://dog.com).

Now, what I then essentially want are `NSRange`s for each of the texts appearing inside tags and their type (but taking the tag out of the equation). So for example, for the text above I would get:

```
NSRange boldRange = NSMakeRange(4, 3);
NSRange italicRange = NSMakeRange(20, 5);
NSRange urlRange = NSMakeRange(35, 8);
```

I am thinking this should be done as a loop so that I can add formatting to the NSAttributedString I am creating and of course save out the URL ranges to a separate array so I can create the links during display.

Are there any libraries out there to assist me. I'll try to update this question as I find things.

Comment: Hi did you found anything new ?

Comment: No, I implemented my own.

Comment: Can you share how you did it? on Github or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try OHAttributedLabel, it can display html strings like you are asking.